# mysql search by time on time stamp

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with this issue for a while now any solutions are welcomed.

I have a table in MySQL and i am storing a `timestamp`.

Now lets say if i search on the basis of only date it works.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  timestamp > "2012-03-12";
```

this fetches all data where timestamp value is greater than 2012-03-12 00:00:00.

what i want is a query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  timestamp > "10:20:09";
```

where all records with tie greater than 10:20:09 is fetched irrespective of the date.

Comment: Check out MySQL datetime functions. You can extract the time component from a timestamp and query on that.

Comment: you could store date and time in separate columns to make it easier. But use Mysql DATE_FORMAT() function to get the time from the date

Comment: i have already looked that up. but i didn't get it much. Can you give a little more detail or an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this statement (it will get the time from your datetime column and compare it with the time)

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(yourDatecolumn, '%H:%i:s') > '10:20:00'
```

**Warning**
This time format is for EU times (where 1pm = 13), if you want US format, use '%h:%i:s'